# what i give project output path

Tags: next.js, sanity

I run this command

```
"npm install -g @sanity/cli && sanity init --template getting-started-pets --project abgfpdhd --dataset production --provider google"
changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 16s

found 0 vulnerabilities
You're setting up a Sanity.io project!
We'll make sure you're logged in with Sanity.io.     
Then, we'll install a Sanity Studio for your project.

Press ctrl + C at any time to quit.

Looks like you already have a Sanity-account. Sweet! 

? Project output path: (E:\Ecommerce\ecommerce\moccasin-dunlin)
```

I don't know. What I give project output path

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `next.config.js` and add the distDir config in nextjs, and your problem is solved.

```
module.exports = {
  distDir: 'build',
}
```